# Crypsetup (Unix) is not reading my device

Tags: linux, unix, luks

I have a Unix based question.

Intro:

Trying to create local image which is coded by the cryptsetup tool. Here are my steps:

> abcdef# dd if=/dev/zero of=image.img bs=512M count=1 
> 1+0 records in 
> 1+0 records out 
> 536870912 bytes (537 MB) copied,
> 6.39732 s, 83.9 MB/s 
> abcdef# cryptsetup luksFormat image.img
> WARNING! 
> ======== 
> This will overwrite data on image.img irrevocably. 
> Are you sure? (Type uppercase yes): *YES* 
> Cannot read device image.img.

Q:
How can I make it work correctly(creating local image with crypting support) or how can I (if its possible of course) to swindle my os? Any idea's ? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use loopback device for this:

```
losetup /dev/loop0 image.img
cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/loop0
```

Probable next steps:

```
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/loop0 qqq
mkfs.ext3 /dev/mapper/qqq
mount /dev/mapper/qqq /mnt/tmp/

# work with mounted container in /mnt/tmp

umount /mnt/tmp/
cryptsetup luksClose qqq
losetup -d /dev/loop0
```